Possible validity of transfinite model construction for $\mathsf{ZFC}^- + \mathsf{AFA}$
I'm attempting to construct a model for $\mathsf{ZFC}^- + \mathsf{AFA}$ (Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory + Choice, minus Foundation and together with Aczel's Anti-Foundation Axiom) off an arbitrary model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (so please no spoilers as to how it's actually done).
I had the following doubt as to whether the following idea for a model construction would actually be a valid one: Suppose we had some equivalence relation $\sim$ which intuitively (I won't go into the specifics of how it operates) expresses that two graphs are "analogous." Under a well-founded context, such analogy coincides with identical decorations for the aforementioned graphs. Thus, as $2 = \{0, 1\} = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ both decorates a graph like $(\{1, 2, 3, 4\}, \{(1,2), (1,3), (3,4)\})$ and a graph like $(\{1,2,3\},\{(1,2),(1,3),(3,2)\})$, we would say both such graphs are analogous, i.e., related by $\sim$.
My idea is then the following: We say two sets are "equivalent" whenever their induced graphs (i.e., the graph formed by taking all its elements as nodes and all its belonging relations via $\in$ as edges) are analogous. I'm wondering now whether the following would be a valid move: Given Löwenheim-Skolem, we can work with a countable model $\langle M, \in_M \rangle$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Also due to LS, we can work with some extension $\langle M', \in'_M \rangle$ of our original model of a higher cardinality. Let's say $\langle M, \in_M \rangle$ has continuum cardinality, just because.
Now, because $M'$ is of a higher cardinality than $M$, there must be uncountably many $m \in M'-M$! Here comes the (possibly) problematic idea: As $M$ is countable, we know that its subset defined by $\{m \in M : M \models \mathrm{Graph}(m) \}$ ($\mathrm{Graph}(m)$ here expresses that $m$ is a graph, of course) is countable also. Not only that, we also know that for each such $m \in M$, the set $\{n \in M : M \models \mathrm{Node}_m(n)\}$ (where $\mathrm{Node}_m(n)$ intuitively expresses that $n$ is a node for $m$ a graph) is also countable!
Thus, if we were to consider all such $n$ for all such $m$, it would amount to a countable Cartesian product of countable sets, i.e., there would be an uncountable amount of them. Not a problem, however! As we have uncountably many $m \in M'-M$ to spare!
Let us thus perform the following transfinite construction (herein lies what I'm pretty sceptical of regarding validity): We first set a well-order $<$ on our $m \in \mathrm{Graph}(M)$. Now, for the very first such $m$, we consider its set of nodes $\mathrm{Node}(m)$ and add countably many $m \in M'-M$ in bijection with its members to our original $M$. Not only that, we add also to $\in_M$ the ordered pairs $(m, n)$ for $m,n \in M'-M$ whenever their respective images formed an edge of the graph under consideration. Once done with all this, we move on to the second graph and repeat the same process, only making sure to add countably many $m \in M'-M$ in bijection with its nodes that we didn't already add before. Thus, for the graph $m_\alpha$, we shall be looking at the set $M'-M-\bigcup_{\beta < \alpha}M_\beta$ to take our countably many sets to put in bijection with $m_\alpha$'s nodes (here $M_\beta$ is, of course, the sets that we took from $M'$ in stage $\beta$).
With each such stage (notice they are independent, i.e., always over the same original set $M$) we obtain an altered $M_\alpha$, and once we have obtained all such $M_\alpha$ we take $N = \bigcup_{0 : \omega}M_\alpha$. Once we have our $N$... we quotient it by our previously defined relation of equivalence! (We have added "atoms" originally from $M'$ into $M$ and made them reproduce each possible graph in $M$ via belonging relations $\in$, thus we can immediately consider each and every one of their induced graphs —which shall coincide with the very graphs that originated them— and quotient those same graphs by our $\sim$ relation!)
Such a set $N/\sim$ will then surely work as a model for $\mathsf{ZFC}^- + \mathsf{AFA}$! Is this idea actually valid? Is the whole transfinite recursion schtick well formulated? Please let me know!
Many thanks in advance to any and all who may waste their precious time reading all this ;)

Aside from your question, I am really curious if you read Aczel's proof for the consistency of the Antifoundation axiom. Is there any reason to reinvent the wheel?

@HanulJeon I have not! I know only of his Axiom and I have been actively avoiding looking up his proof/model construction as a sort of personal mathematical challenge! I know it's not that productive as it technically is just as you said: attempting to reinvent the wheel... but oh well :P It's fun! And I think it's helped me think a tad bit better (mathematically at least). I've already attempted something similar before by trying to encode finite lists of naturals into $\mathsf{PA}$ without looking up Gödel's own $\beta$-function... (And it worked!)

@HanulJeon I'm really curious though as if I might actually be close to providing a valid model and what I sketched above really might work...

I haven't looked at your argument in detail, but I am unsure the meaning of '... if we were to consider all such $n$ for all such $m$.' It sounds like you consider the set of ordered pairs ${(m,n)\mid M\vDash \text{Graph}(m)\land \text{Node}_m(n)}$, which is countable, am I correct? If my understanding is correct, considering $M'$ might be unnecessary.

@HanulJeon I think you are correct, yeah! I think considering $M'$ is still necessary (at least as to my argument) because that's where I'm getting my extra, not-related-to-any-of-$M$'s-elements sets from!

@HanulJeon But I am a bit confused because now that I think of it, yeah, ${(m, n) \in M \times M : M \models \mathrm{Graph}(m) \land \mathrm{Node}(m, n)}$ should indeed be countable (as $M \times M$ is)... but also my previous argument seemed to suggest it should be uncountable? (I.e., we have countably many $m$ to consider, and for each of these $m$ there can be countably many $n$ as their nodes, so it should be a countable Cartesian product of countable sets? Perhaps my mistake was in taking these $n$ to be non-repeating or something of that sort?)

You are conflating a countable union with a countable product.

@HanulJeon I just realized "but I'm doing the countable union not the countable product!" and came to rectify what I said but it seems you already did hshs. Sorry for the slight confusion there! Anyway, yes, I'm considering the countable set of such ordered pairs (and getting countably many elements from $M'$ —which $M$ doesn't take as its own elements— to put in bijection with them and their respective relations).
